# Get filename from openfiledialog by clicking a browse button

Tags: powershell

Basically what I want to do is have a browse button which opens a openfiledialog window and allows me to select a file and save the filename into a variable so I can use it elsewhere. I have the following function from [Hey, Scripting Guy! Can I Open a File Dialog Box with Windows PowerShell?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/):

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.FileName
} #end function Get-FileName
```

Which when run on its own will open the dialogwindow and output the file I selected to the console window. When I add the button event in to pop-open the dialog window I use `$button1.add_Click({Get-FileName})` Which when clicked opens the dialog window but I am not sure how to get the filename (the file selected in the dialog window) out  into its own variable. I feel like I am close but I just need a little direction any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The property `$OpenFileDialog.FileName` will be output from the function because it is not otherwise being assigned or captured anywhere.  Does `$selectedPath = Get-FileName('C:\WINDOWS')` not work as expected?  By the way, you may want to change the last two lines to `if ($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) { $OpenFileDialog.FileName }` just to handle the case where the user cancels the dialog.

Comment: Yes, `$selectedPath = Get-FileName('C:\WINDOWS')` does work as intended just not in the `$button1.add_click({})` event.

Comment: We'll probably need to see the code for your form with the button.  Also, I haven't done a lot Windows Forms programming from PowerShell, but I think you need to use the [`Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849929.aspx) for registering event handlers.  Something like `Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $button1 -EventName 'Click' -Action { $selectedPath = Get-FileName('C:\WINDOWS') }`, though I'm not thinking `$selectedPath` will survive outside of the `ScriptBlock`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you assign the variable within the script block where the function is called? Make sure your variable is declared first outside the button click script block:

```
$global:variable = $null
$button1.add_Click({$global:variable = Get-FileName})
```

Comment: This Worked, Also I noticed that I had the function for the the dialog box and also another function to create the window form so it was calling the function from another function. I removed the function to create the windows form and got it working without the need for global variables. Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code it looks like you just need to declare the filename property into a variable. Try this, filename selected will be stored in `$SelectedFile`:

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.Title = "Please Select File"
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
    # Out-Null supresses the "OK" after selecting the file.
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $Global:SelectedFile = $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}
```

Comment: This would also work if `$SelectedFile` is a global variable.